# How to update the data of a grandchild component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, window.open

So I am using 'react-popout' from https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/react-popout to create a popout window has this subWindow component which has its own data fields in it. I have a MainComponent which defines a list of these popoutwindows (there can be mulitple) and as I define this list I also define that the PopoutWindow has a child subWindow (I leave PopoutWindow component package alone). The PopoutWindow is a wrapper.

So I call the subWindow as part of PopoutWindow inside MainComponent and I want to be able to change the data that I pass into subWindow (currentWindowData) and trigger a re-render but right now it is not working AND I want to only change the data of just one of these PopoutWindows in the list, and not any others.

How can I have it so that upon say a button click, I change the data of only ONE of the subWindows but not all of them (assuming multiple PopoutWindows are rendered and in the list)?

```
<MainComponent>

openWindow() {
    const keyId = shortid.generate();
    const window=   <PopoutWindow
                            title={keyId}
                            options={{height: '700px', width: '350px'}}
                            key={keyId}
                        >
                            {
                        <subWindow key={shortid.generate()} 
                              data={this.state.currentWindowData} 
                        />}
                   </PopoutWindow>;

    this.setState({
        renderSubWindow: true,
        subWindowArray: [window, ...this.state.subeWindowArray],

    });
}
```

Comment: Can you not use an array for `this.state.currentWindowData` and refer to it by key?

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks. I'll try that out and let you know how it goes once I get any data in the child to re-render. That's what I'm stuck on right now.

How do I get the subWindow data to rerender, I'm calling setState upon button click in a different function but for whatever reason it's not re-rendering the data in subWindow.

Comment: Use the `willReceiveProps` lifecycle hook in the `subWindow` component to listen to changes in the `data` prop and re-render accordingly. Should work

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. For whatever reason it's not triggering. Could it because it's a grandchild I'm trying to update?

Comment: I found the error. It worked when I started recalling this openWindow method whenever I setState for new data change. Before I only called this openWindow initially. 

Any ideas why? Is it because I had to call setState againn for renderSubWindow and/or subWindoArray?